# Adding JComboBox to the JTable

Tags: swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jcombobox, jcomponent

I am using this code to add the `JCombobox` to `JTable`, but when i m running this code , no combobox is added to the `Jtable` only header is shown in the `Jtable`.

```
Private JTable ScrollPaneTable;

public JTable getScrollPaneTable()
    {
        if(ScrollPaneTable == null)
        {
            try
            {
                ScrollPaneTable = new JTable();
                ScrollPaneTable.setName("ScrollPaneTable");
                getJScrollPane1().setColumnHeaderView(ScrollPaneTable.getTableHeader());
                TableColumn sportColumn = ivjScrollPaneTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
                sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(getCombo1())); //getCombo1                      
                            returns the JCombo box reference whose items are already added.
                ScrollPaneTable.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
            }
            catch(Throwable Exc)
            {
                handleException(Exc);
            }
        }
        return ScrollPaneTable;
    }
```

Here I am adding only one combo but there is more combos I want to use in other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), this works for me,

```
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TestJComboBox {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example of JCombobox in JTable");
        frame.setSize(450, 250);

        JTable table = new JTable(5,5);

        TableColumn testColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("This");
        comboBox.addItem("is");
        comboBox.addItem("a");
        comboBox.addItem("Sample program");
        comboBox.addItem("for");
        comboBox.addItem("StackOverflow");
        testColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

        frame.add(table);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```